# query to print stud id if the student count for city is greater than 3

Tags: mysql

I have a table details with the following structure

```
details(
    studid int primary key, 
    fname varchar(20) not null, 
    lname varchar(20) not null, 
    DOB date not null, 
    city varchar(20)
);
```

I am required total number of students who have live in more than 3 cities

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am required total number of students who have live in more than 3 cities :  What does this mean?  You cant have a duplicate student id with more than 1 city with the structure you have provided.  Can you please show us your database table if possible ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.